# Add new language on Windows Phone store description for app created with Phonegap

Tags: cordova, windows-phone, phonegap-build, windows-store

I have created a Windows Phone app with Phonegap and uploaded it to Windows Phone Store successfully. However, the only description I am allowed to enter in the store is in English.

How can I add any further languages? Is there something I need to change on config.xml?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to add multi language support in your project. 
Then when the app package uploaded, store will automatically offer you descriptions for different languages like this:

1. Descriptions
2. Chinese (China)
3. English (United States)